# Как вставить функцию которое находится в другом функции на variable?

Tags: python

Мне нужно вставить функцию которое находится в другом функции на variable Calculator

```
def Calculate(str):
    def Calculate2(str):
        print(int(eval(str)))
Calculator = Calculate2
Calculator(input())
```

Этот код даёт ошибку
NameError: name 'Calculate2' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Calculate'?
Я даже попробовал так

```
def Calculate(str):
    global Calculate2
    def Calculate2(str):
        print(int(eval(str)))
Calculator = Calculate2
Calculator(input())
```

Но всё равно та ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `return Calculate2`

```
def Calculate():
    def Calculate2(expression):
        print(int(eval(expression)))
    return Calculate2
Calculator = Calculate()
Calculator(input('Введите выражение: '))
```

Переменную c именем `str` лучше не использовать, чтобы не перекрывать встроенный объект `str`

```
Введите выражение: 1+2+3
6
```

Comment: Можно  ли копировать  код этой функции  на тот Calculator

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
def calculate(string: str):
    def do_calc(s):
        return int(eval(s))
    return do_calc(string)


print(calculate('100 * 15'))
```